# How do we use smart pointers with CFileDialog and multi-file selection?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, smart-pointers, openfiledialog

How about modernizing our code that uses the common [`CFileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class?view=msvc-160) dialog?

Sample code:

```
void CExportSettingsDlg::OnBnClickedMfcbuttonImportXsl()
{
    CString strFilter;                                  // This will be used to display the right type of template files
    CString strTargetFolder = theApp.GetWorkingPath();  // Default
    TCHAR* pszFile = new TCHAR[32767];                  // Buffer for the files selected by the user
    TCHAR szTabText[_MAX_PATH] = { 0 };                 // Buffer for the selected tab text (we use it for the filter description)

    // Initialise the filter string
    strFilter = _T("Styles|SRRSchedule*.xsl;SRRSchedule*.css||");

    // Initialise the file dialog
    CFileDialog dlgImport(TRUE,
        _T(".XSL"), _T(""), OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, strFilter, this);
    ZeroMemory(pszFile, 32767 * sizeof(TCHAR));
    dlgImport.m_ofn.lpstrFile = pszFile;
    dlgImport.m_ofn.nMaxFile = 32767;
    dlgImport.m_ofn.nFileOffset = 0;

    if (dlgImport.DoModal() != IDOK)
    {
        // User did not select any files so tidy up the memory
        delete[] pszFile;
        return;
    }

    // Iterate the selected files
    POSITION pos = dlgImport.GetStartPosition();
    CString strSourceFilePath, strTargetFilePath, strSourceFileName, strSourceFileTitle, strSourceExtension, strFileName;

    while (pos)
    {
        strSourceFilePath = dlgImport.GetNextPathName(pos);
        // ...
    }

    // Tidy memory
    delete[] pszFile;
}
```

How can we turn this into using a smart pointer? The `lpstrFile` variable is of type `LPWSTR`.

Comment: In this case the simplest would be just `TCHAR* pszFile = new TCHAR[32767];` -> `TCHAR pszFile[32767] = {0};`

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't know if it applied in this case, but sometimes you get stack size warnings when using too much memory (don't remember right terms). I'll let @ Iinspectable comment.

Comment: Yes, it's not a good idea to have large local variables (which are stored on the stack on most platforms). But 32767 is not that much.

Comment: @Jabberwocky You will still get teh pointer decay warning when you do it like you said. Unless I change `dlgImport.m_ofn.lpstrFile = &pszFile[0];`. Then it is OK.

Comment: @jab *"32767 is not that much"* - That's 64KiB in a UNICODE build. With a default stack size of 1MiB, that accounts for 6.25% of available stack space, just for this single array. That's **a lot**. Things are even worse for 64-bit builds, exacerbated by the 64-bit calling convention, where the stack needs to be 16-byte aligned, plus 32 bytes of shadow space (for every function call except leaf functions). That's a lot of pressure on the stack, best to not add to that if at all possible. It is possible here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you need an automatically managed, heap-allocated array, [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is the go-to solution. All `new[]`'s and `delete[]`'s will miraculously disappear, and the parameters set in the `OPENFILENAME` structure will match, as a bonus.

Something like this:

```cpp
void CExportSettingsDlg::OnBnClickedMfcbuttonImportXsl()
{
    // ...
    // The controlled sequence is default-initialized (i.e. zeroed out)
    auto pszFile = std::vector<TCHAR>(32767);

    // ...

    // Initialise the file dialog
    CFileDialog dlgImport(TRUE,
        _T(".XSL"), _T(""), OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, strFilter, this);
    dlgImport.m_ofn.lpstrFile = pszFile.data();
    // Without the cast this would raise a signed/unsigned mismatch warning
    // depending on the target architecture
    dlgImport.m_ofn.nMaxFile = static_cast<uint32_t>(pszFile.size());
    dlgImport.m_ofn.nFileOffset = 0;

    if (dlgImport.DoModal() != IDOK)
    {
        // User did not select any files so simply return
        // Memory is cleaned up by vector's d'tor
        return;
    }

    // ...

    // No need to clean up
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `TCHAR pszFile[32767] = {0};` be good enough here?

Comment: @jab It would, if you were fine to use up up to 64KiB of your 1MiB stack space. Lots of diagnostics are coming your way when you do.

Comment: Stack usage is an argument for using a vector, but OTOH it's easy to increment the stack size so some more reasonable size like 8Mib.

Comment: @jab That's possible, sure, but why would you want to do this here? This isn't performance critical code, and taking the non-trivial cost of a heap allocation isn't going to be noticeable in practice. There doesn't seem to be any immediate value in avoiding a standard container.